# What would cause the Rule error: Invalid property access: target is not an object?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

MY RT DB

```
"people" : {
 “userA uid” : {
   "CarDealers: {
     "optionalMdufbehjbfhe" : "**IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1**", 
 ////this is childbyAutoID:UID of UserB///
   }
  }
```

I want to make sure that uid in the double is the current user when he wants to write, ie auth.uid. So for the write rule I make:

```
,"CarDealers" : {
  "$CarDealers_id": {
       ".read": "auth.uid != null",
       ".write": "auth.uid === data.child.val('CarDealers_id')",
    }  
   }
```

So why am I getting an error:Invalid property access: target is not an object?-

Comment: 1) The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both. 2) Please show the minimal code too that generates the error.

Comment: my bad, will not include firestore again. The code that causes the error is simply the rule: `auth.uid === data.child.val('CarDealers_id')"` that I put in the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with hidden characters in the string. Deleting the whole line and rewriting it or copying the same value from another line (not copy and paste the same line again!!!) fixed the problem for me, even if the visible text did not change a bit.